# Vertically center text without table-cell and line-height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I have this page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sntfh.png) and I want the text to be vertically center aligned. I can't use table-cell because when I do, it displays all items in the same row, and that's not the case, as you can see in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sntfh.png). I can't set a fixed line-height also, because each text has a size.

> my css

```
img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 81px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

> my html

```
<p>
  <img src="../assets/imagens/recomendacoes_tenis.png">
  Devido ao fato de grande parte do calçamento da cidade ser feito em pedras e, por isso escorregadio, evite o uso de sapatos de salto e/ou desconfortáveis. Dê preferência aos tênis.
</p>
<p>
   <img src="../assets/imagens/recomendacoes_mochila.png">
   Evite peso extra. Há muitas ladeiras e escadarias na cidade, por isso, prefira mochilas e pastas menores e mais leves, carregue somente o essêncial. Em alguns atrativos será solicitado que bolsas, mochilas e equipamentos fotográficos sejam guardados na recepção.
</p>
        ...
```

[how it it is looking now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sntfh.png)

Can someone help me to do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the parent of an image to `flex` and the `align-items` property to `center`.

```
img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 81px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Code](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/VqaYYY)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 now includes some vertical-align classes.

```
<div class="align-middle">
    this text is vertically aligned in the middle!
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/

Comment: It didn't work :( I tried just putting class align-middle and also tried setting the height to the same size as the side image, but none of the ways worked.